# Trying to print() to return a bool

Tags: swift, printing, boolean, return

I'm doing Angela Yu's iOS Swift course. I'm on Lesson 082 at 5:10 on timeline.

Here's the code example being I'm working on:

```
func loveCalli() {
    /** **ASSIGNMENT** SINGLE '=' SIGN */
    
    let loveNumber = Int.random(in: 0...100)
    
    /** **CHECKING** DOUBLE '==' SIGNS */
    
    if loveNumber > 80 {
        print(Bool().self, "; You'll love each other like Kanya loves Kanya.")
    } else if loveNumber > 40 || loveNumber < 80 {
        print(Bool().self, "; You go together like Coke and Mentos.")
    } else {
        print(Bool().self, "; You'll be forever alone.")
    }
}

loveCalli()
```

Is it possible to print result as a `Bool!`? The result I am looking for is:

If the random number is above 80, I would like it to print:

> "true ; You'll love each other like Kanya loves Kanya."

If the random number is below 80, I would like it to print:

> "false ; You'll love each other like Kanya loves Kanya."

but even when the number is above 80, I'm getting

> "false ; You'll love each other like Kanya loves Kanya."

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of doing `if loveNumber > 80 {` you should do `let over80 = loveNumber > 80` and then `print(over80, "...")`

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is coming from `Bool().self`. Let me break it down:

- `Bool` is the boolean type, itself.
- `Bool()` is invoking the initializer on `Bool` to create a new `Bool` instance.

  - This is shorthand for `Bool.init()`
  - The result is always `false`. So `Bool()` is equivalent to `false`, the same way `Int()` is equivalent to `0`.
- `Bool().self` is accessing the `self` property of that `false`. `self` is a property that always returns the thing its called on.

So `Bool().self` will *always* be `false`.

Reading between the lines a little bit, I think this is what you're looking for is to have a boolean value that says whether a subject is "lovable" or not. Looking from the print messages, it looks like a subject is lovable if the number is above 40 (even more so if it's above `80`), so I added: `let isLoveable = 40 < loveNumber`

Here's how that might look:

```
func loveCalli() {
    /** **ASSIGNMENT** SINGLE '=' SIGN */
    
    let loveNumber = Int.random(in: 0...100)
    let isLoveable = 40 < loveNumber

    /** **CHECKING** DOUBLE '==' SIGNS */
    
    if loveNumber > 80 {
        print(isLoveable, "; You'll love each other like Kanya loves Kanya.")
    } else if isLoveable || loveNumber < 80 {
        print(isLoveable, "; You go together like Coke and Mentos.")
    } else {
        print(isLoveable, "; You'll be forever alone.")
    }
}

loveCalli()
```